# Parcelable works without correct implementation

Tags: java, android, parcelable

In a Android App I'm sending a Bundle from an Activity to a Fragment.

```
public class Bar implements Parcelable {

private Map<String, String> hash;
private int id;

protected Bar(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
}

public Bar(int id, Map<String,String> map){
    this.hash=map;
    this.id=id;
}

public static final Creator<Bar> CREATOR = new Creator<Bar>() {
    @Override
    public Bar createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Bar(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Bar[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Bar[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(id);
}
}
```

I've used Android Studios Implement Parcelable inteli sense help and auto generated the above code and it has no implementation for the Map.

When I send this to my Fragment like this:

```
 Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("foo","bar");
    map.put("foobar","barfoo");
    Bar foo = new Bar(1,map);

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    bundle.putParcelable("foo",foo);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "foo");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And somehow the Map appears to contain the content when it appears in the fragment. Why is this? The behaviour I would excpect is that Id is transfered and Map is skipped.
This is possible to repeat by just creating an Activity, a fragment and my Bar and send it as a Bundle.
I've tried searching for an answer but I'm not quite sure on how to formulate the question.

Is it a bug or a feature that is supposed to work this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parceling is done lazily, which means your `Bar` instance is not being parceled when you pass it to the `Fragment`. I.e. `writeToParcel` is not called.

Parceling is quite expensive (in terms of resources), so it's better to avoid it if possible. If the `Bundle` is not sent to another process there is no need to parcel it. Usually parceling is done when IPC is involved. So even during a configuration change there is no need to parcel the `Bundle`. If, however, your process is killed when the activity is in the background, the arguments `Bundle` would be parceled because it's stored in another process.
This is also true when you send it in an `Intent`.

So in your case the `Map` would go lost when the instance is actually parceled. It's only still present because it's not really parceled and the Fragment receives the exact same instance of `Bar`.

Comment: Where can I read more about this? Would it also work between Activities? And instead of putParcelable I coculd Use putSerializable andhave the same effect??

Comment: I mostly learned it by "accident" and from digging into the Android sources. See [`putParcelable`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Bundle.java#448), it essentially just stores the `Parcelable` in a `Map` (after unparceling its contents if it was parceled before).
Not sure what you mean by "works" because `Bar` essentially doesn't work. Whenever Android decides that the `Bundle` needs to be parceled it will fail and the `Map` won't be restored properly.

Comment: When you add this `Bundle` to an `Intent` to start another activity, it's most certainly being parceled (without your `Map`), so the receiving activity won't see any map. I'm pretty sure that's even the case for activities in the same process.
If `Bar` would implement `Serializable` instead of `Parcelable` your `Map` might survive parcelation if it implements `Serializable` as well. But that depends on the actual map you pass to `Bar`. There are `Map` implementations which are not `Serializable`, e.g. `WeakHashMap`. Passing such a map would result in a `NotSerializableException`.

Comment: Ok, but then this will work in my case for opening a new Fragment, I've changed the Bundle to use PutSerializable instead of Parcelable to make it clear, I still don't like how it didn't parcel the object when I told it to do it, but I will see if I can find some more info somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Bundle has not only **Parcelable** objects storing implementation, but also **Serializable**. If you look at HashMap's class you'll see it implements Serializable interface:

```
public class HashMap<K,V>
extends AbstractMap<K,V>
implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
```